# using this. in a jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In a javascript program there is an array (gData) that contains objects.
Each of these objects has a property called label that is an object.
each label contains a span called span_ within a div called div_.

Amongst other gData related operations, the label object is instantiated as

`gData.label = new Label();`

and then the gData object is pushed onto the gData array.

In the main program, i can execute the following jquery code that works fine:

`$(gData[0].label.span_).css("border","5px solid green");`

I want to add a function prototype to the label object called setCSS().  I would call the setCSS method like this:

```
gData[0].label.setCSS("border","5px solid green");
```

The setCSS code that I wrote (below) does not work.  I'm guessing that the selector isn't working.

```
Label.prototype.setCSS = function(args) {

// args contains an object in the form {"cssAtribute":"cssData"}
// call this method as label.setCSS({"border":"3px solid blue"});
// Any number of css attributes can be included in the args object

    $.each(args, function(theKey, theValue) {
        $(this.span_).css(theKey, theValue);
    });
}
```

I've tried $(this.span_), $(this.div.span_) and several other selectors, none work.

Using Firebug I can see that gData[0] contains a label object and the label object contains a span_ object.  Is my selector specification wrong?  or have I missed some other cause that will make me feel dumb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside a `jQuery.each` will have a different scope. You need to save it first in a local variable:

```
var $span = $(this.span_);
$.each(args, function(theKey, theValue) {
    $span.css(theKey, theValue);
});
```

Note that you example `.setCSS("border","5px solid green");` will not work using this method, as it requires the argument to be an object using key/values.

However, you should be able to simplify the method to:

```
Label.prototype.setCSS = function() {
    $.prototype.css.apply($(this.span_), $.makeArray(arguments));
};
```

That way you can use it the same way jQuery uses `.css()` including your implementation example.

**Fiddles:**

First example: http://jsfiddle.net/ESrSY

Second example: http://jsfiddle.net/UpEPK

Comment: Code below, as ammended per your suggestion, still doesn't work. `var $span = $(this.span_);
  $.each(args, function(theKey, theValue) {
    $span.css(theKey, theValue);
  });`

Comment: The first example works here: http://jsfiddle.net/ESrSY/ and the second example here: http://jsfiddle.net/UpEPK/